# How to store only the desired values in Django View

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm a student learning Django for the first time. I want to save only the values I want in Django's View, but I don't know what to do. Below are Models.py and Views.py, forms.py. I want to save it by entering only one without entering second_value and third_value in value_name. Please help me a lot.

```js
def product_upload(request):
    current_category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.all()
    photos = Photo.objects.all()
    designated_object = Designated.objects.all()
    options = Option.objects.all()
    slug = Product.slug

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            product = Product()
            product.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            product.benefit = form.cleaned_data['benefit']
            product.detail = form.cleaned_data['detail']
            product.target_price = form.cleaned_data['target_price']
            product.start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
            product.due_date = form.cleaned_data['due_date']
            product.category_code = form.cleaned_data['category_code']
            product.image = request.FILES['photo']
            product.username = request.user
            product.slug = slug
            product.kakao_link = form.cleaned_data['kakao_link']
            product.save()

        for img in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
            photo = Photo()
            photo.product_code = product
            photo.photo = img
            photo.save()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = OptionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            option = Option()
            option.name = form.cleaned_data['option_name']
            option.product_code = product
            option.save()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ValueForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            value = Value()
            value.name = form.cleaned_data['value_name']
            value.option_code = option
            value.product_code = product
            value.extra_cost = form.cleaned_data['option_price']
            value.save()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ValueForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            value = Value()
            value.name = form.cleaned_data['second_value']
            value.option_code = option
            value.product_code = product
            value.extra_cost = form.cleaned_data['second_option_price']
            value.save()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ValueForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            value = Value()
            value.name = form.cleaned_data['third_value']
            value.option_code = option
            value.product_code = product
            value.extra_cost = form.cleaned_data['third_option_price']
            value.save()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DesignatedForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            designated = Designated()
            designated.price = form.cleaned_data['price']
            designated.product_code = product
            designated.rep_price = True
            designated.save()


            return render(request, 'zeronine/list.html', {'form': form,
                                                          'current_category': current_category,
                                                          'photos':photos,
                                                          'options':options,
                                                          'products': products,
                                                          'categories': categories,
                                                          'slug': slug, })
    else:
        form = ProductForm()

    return render(request, 'product/product_upload.html',{'form': form,
                                                          'current_category': current_category,
                                                          'photos':photos,
                                                          'options':options,
                                                          'products': products,
                                                          'categories': categories})
```

```css
class ValueForm(forms.Form):
    value_name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': "옵션값을 입력하세요."}, max_length=32, label="옵션명")
    second_value = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': "두번째 옵션값을 입력하세요."}, max_length=32, label="second_value")
    third_value = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': "세번째 옵션값을 입력하세요."}, max_length=32, label="third_value")
    option_price = forms.IntegerField(error_messages={'required': "옵션명을 입력하세요."}, label="옵션추가비용")
    second_option_price = forms.IntegerField(error_messages={'required': "옵션명을 입력하세요."}, label="second_option_price")
    third_option_price = forms.IntegerField(error_messages={'required': "옵션명을 입력하세요."}, label="third_option_price")
```

```html
class Value(models.Model):
    value_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    option_code = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='option_code', null=True, blank=True)
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    extra_cost = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What are the 'only values'?

Comment: Why do you have so many `if request.method == "POST"`? It'll cause an error.